# Sequelize Typescript Nestjs Filters

Tags: sql, postgresql, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I have 2 tables: Products and Filters. Relation: One Product has many Filters.
Can I select all Products that have all these Filters?

Here is part of Filters's table:

| col: name | col: group | col: productId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | group1 | 1 |
| value2 | group2 | 1 |
| value2 | group2 | 2 |

```js
const filters = {
  group1: 'value1',
  group2: 'value2',
  // ...
};

await this.productService.fillAll({
  include: {
    [Op.and]: Object.entries(filters).map(([group, value]) => ({
      group,
      value
    })),
  }
})

//[{group: 'group1', value: 'value1'},{group: 'group2', value: 'value2'}]
```

After that findAll, I must get only productId: [1], because productId = 2 does not have {group: 'group1', value: 'value1'}

```js
  ...

  private getFilters(filters: { [key: string]: string }) {
    return {
      [Op.and]: Object.entries(filters).map(([group, value]) => ({
        group,
        value
      })),
    };
  }

  ...

  if (filters) {
    findOptions.include = [
      {
       model: Filters,
       where: this.getFilters(filters),
      },
    ];
  }

  findOptions.offset = (offset - 1) * limit;
  findOptions.limit = limit;
  findOptions.order = [['createdAt', 'DESC']];
  
  const { count, rows: products } =
      await this.productRepository.findAndCountAll(findOptions);


  ...
```